# In perl I am parsing a log file with 2 regular expressions but the regular expressions are not quite working it seems

Tags: regex, perl

My main part of the regular expression is this

```
my $filename = "/opt/bmc/ARSystem/AREmail/Logs/emaild.sh_log.1";
my $starttag = "A14 FETCH 1";
my $endtag = "A14 OK FETCH completed.";
my $element = "";

if(checkFile($filename)) {
    open (MYFILE, $filename);
    my @lines = <MYFILE>;
    close(MYFILE);
    foreach $line(@lines){
      print if /$starttag/../$endtag/;

       $element .= $line;
    }
    #print $element;
    my @matched = $element =~ /$starttag(.*?)$endtag/mg;
    #my @matched = $element =~ /$starttag/mg;
    #my @matched1 = $element =~ /$endtag/mg;

    print scalar(@matched);
```

When I run the script @matched comes up empty. Am I doing something wrong? I have verified the elements are in the  log file. They span multiple lines and all. It is basically retrieving an email that is in the log file the the starttag and end tag separate the emails.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using a proper IMAP client rather than parsing the logs of one?

Answer (score 3):

Since `$element` spans multiple lines, you should be using the `/s` modifier on your regex to make `.` match newlines.  Using the `/m` modifier, as you have, only alters the behavior of `^` and `$`.